# Java: How to add lists to a list based on length or sum of values?

Tags: java, java-8

I have a requirement to create a list of lists where the each list if of length 5 or the sum of the values in the list is <= 10 (whichever happens first). So far I have:

```
    int currentSize = 0;
    Boolean size = false;
    Boolean length = false;

    for (int s : keyListMax) {

      if(currentSize >= 10) {
        sizeReached = true;
      }

      if(currentList.size() >= 5) {
        lengthReached = true;
      }

      if(!sizeReached && !lengthReached) {
        currentSize += currentList.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
        currentList.add(s);
      }
      else {
        result.add(0, currentList);
        currentList.clear();
        currentSize = 0;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Result is: " + result);
```

But the result is list of empty lists (maybe because of the clear() I’m using?). Also, how can I achieve this using Java 8?

Comment: It looks like you're just adding `currentList` to `result` over and over again.  If you want a different list, you have to use `new` and make one.

Comment: Yes you answered it, you are clearing the list

Comment: Also you should add `s` to `currentList` before calculating the sum

Comment: Is it required to have the list in opposite order, i.e. to use `result.add(0, currentList)` instead of `result.add(currentList)`? depending on the list type, this can be quiet inefficient. Further, there is no reason to use `Boolean` instead of `boolean`, but perhaps `sizeReached` and `lengthReached` are of type `boolean`, as these must be different variables than `size` and `length`.

Answer (score 2):

A much easier solution is just to keep a running total of the elements you have added:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < keyListMax.size()) {
  int start = i;
  int sum = 0;
  do {
    sum += keyListMax.get(i);
    ++i;
  } while (i < keyListMax.size()
      && i < start + 5
      && sum + keyListMax.get(i) <= 10);
  result.add(0, new ArrayList<>(keyListMax.subList(start, i)));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for an easier solution. With this solution, the last item is always added as a single list though the size or length constraints haven’t met. Example. [1,2,3,4,5,0] , the result will be [[0], [5], [1, 2, 3, 4]]

Comment: @NoName ok, try to think about how you can avoid adding it then.

Comment: By the way, you can get rid of the `start == i` condition by using a `do … while` loop.